# Clone the command prompt display properties

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm working with several Windows 10 machines and often installing new OS builds, and I only know how to customize the command prompt display by manually adjusting the font, colors, etc. in the properties dialog. Is there a way to copy the settings from a particular command prompt shortcut and automatically apply them to another shortcut, possibly on another machine?

I don't want the change to affect all command prompts on the machine, so the registry defaults are not an option. For example, I use different color backgrounds for different environments, so I can easily tell them apart. This needs to be applied to each command prompt shortcut separately, not to the global defaults.

Comment: Just to clarify, can you confirm that dbenham's update (1st paragraph), does not do what you need?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but sounds like you can make a copy of the `.lnk` file and then that would copy all the settings too.  Then you can edit the properties of the new copy to adjust it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'll have to try dbenham's suggestion. My question still isn't a duplicate--in 683431, the OP asked a different question! The answer from dbenham is a workaround that does NOT answer the OP's original question at all, though it may solve his issue. This substantially reduces the value of the answer, because someone having that question is very unlikely to read through a long list of answers to a DIFFERENT QUESTION. I would agree that my question is ALREADY ANSWERED, but you are absolutely wrong to say that it is a DUPLICATE QUESTION. Accept your error and move on!